# Finding sum to infinity: $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ \infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, factorial

I am trying to find what this value will converge to
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{ \infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$$

I tried using the Taylor series for $e^x$ but couldn’t figure out how to manipulate it to get the above expression, can someone help me out.

Edit: I have seen the solution, the manipulation required didn’t come to me, is there any resource that you guys can tell me about where I can find/practice more questions like this?